# MongoDB covered query is not able to satisfy query from Index

Tags: mongodb

Here is the my environment details:
I got the sample MongoDB collection or database from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/import-data/). It creates a restaurant collection. One document looks like following:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a6292fd6b741ed385c94524"),
"address" : {
    "building" : "97-22",
    "coord" : [ 
        -73.8601152, 
        40.7311739
    ],
    "street" : "63 Road",
    "zipcode" : "11374"
},
"borough" : "Queens",
"cuisine" : "Jewish/Kosher",
"grades" : [ 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-11-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "Z",
        "score" : 20
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2013-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 13
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2012-08-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 13
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2011-12-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "grade" : "B",
        "score" : 25
    }
],
"name" : "Tov Kosher Kitchen",
"restaurant_id" : "40356068"
```

}

I created two indexes like:

```
db.restaurants.createIndex({"restaurant_id" : 1}, {"name" : "restaurantsid"})
db.restaurants.createIndex({"address.zipcode" : 1}, {"name" : "zipcode"})
```

Indexes are as follows:

```
> db.restaurants.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.restaurants"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "address.zipcode" : 1
        },
        "name" : "zipcode",
        "ns" : "test.restaurants"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "restaurant_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "restaurantsid",
        "ns" : "test.restaurants"
    }
]
```

What I want to achieve here is that I need whole list of restaurant_id's or just zipCodes in the following query. I know there is a index living in memory for it. I wrote a query like this:

```
db.restaurants.find({}, {"address.zipcode" : 1, "_id" : 0}).explain()
```

and the result is:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.restaurants",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {

        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "transformBy" : {
                "address.zipcode" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "714fc0d524cf",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.0",
        "gitVersion" : "a57d8e71e6998a2d0afde7edc11bd23e5661c915"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

It always gives me "stage" : "COLLSCAN".

So now lets just get all the object id's. MongoDB creates one default index on ObjectId's.

```
db.restaurants.find({}, {"_id" : 1}).explain()
```

Result is :

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.restaurants",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {

        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "transformBy" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "714fc0d524cf",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.0",
        "gitVersion" : "a57d8e71e6998a2d0afde7edc11bd23e5661c915"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Its weird that MongoDB does not hit the index however all the data I need, lives in index. Why the winning plan is "COLLSCAN" always?

Same happens with restaurantsid index. Maybe I am missing something.
I also took care of `"_id" : 0` while writing query.

I have to use hint() everytime to make it use of index like this:

```
> db.restaurants.explain("executionStats").find({}, {"address.zipcode" : 1, "_id" : 0}).hint("zipcode")
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.restaurants",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {

        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "transformBy" : {
                "address.zipcode" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "address.zipcode" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "zipcode",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "address.zipcode" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "address.zipcode" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 25359,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 79,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 25359,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "nReturned" : 25359,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 63,
            "works" : 25360,
            "advanced" : 25359,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 199,
            "restoreState" : 199,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "transformBy" : {
                "address.zipcode" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 25359,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 43,
                "works" : 25360,
                "advanced" : 25359,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 199,
                "restoreState" : 199,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "address.zipcode" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "zipcode",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "address.zipcode" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "address.zipcode" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 25359,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "714fc0d524cf",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.0",
        "gitVersion" : "a57d8e71e6998a2d0afde7edc11bd23e5661c915"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Using MongoDB hint at command line is fine but its bad when there are applications running and they can't use hint() from their code. Why MongoDB is not able to use right Index on its own without the use of hint()?

Comment: From the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) the index is only utilized when both query and projection contain the index fields.

Comment: @Veeram So basically I have add the field in query part also and problem is solved. But I don't have any condition to put in query part. I just want whole list from Index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright there is a new flag introduced in 3.6 for the specific case you've. It is disabled by default.

Set this flag if you like to use index

```
mongod --setParameter internalQueryPlannerGenerateCoveredWholeIndexScans=1
```

More info [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20066) & [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30130)

Comment: Np. Yes you can set the option in config file. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#file-format)