# Mongodb query for all values in in an indexed column doesn't use the index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection where I often want to pull the value of a field for all documents in the collection. Specifically, I want to get the "filename" field for all documents. I have an index on this field:

```
{ "v" : 2, "key" : { "filename" : 1.0 }, "name" : "filename_1", "ns" : "testdata.metadata" }
```

However, when I search my logs, it looks like it always does a COLLSCAN to return my results:

```
command testdata.metadata command: find { find: "metadata", filter: {}, projection: { filename: 1.0 }, $db: "testdata" } planSummary: COLLSCAN
```

If I do searches for a particular filename, it does use the index. But shouldn't it also use the index if trying to return all filenames? If mongo doesn't use an index for this, is there any way to speed up the query? This is a common search and shows up often in logs as a slow search.

**Update:**
This does sound like a duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351679/mongodb-covered-query-is-not-able-to-satisfy-query-from-index). I tried the solution posted there (set internalQueryPlannerGenerateCoveredWholeIndexScans=1), but it did not help as far as I can tell. An "explain" after making the change still shows that it is doing a collscan.

The description of the other question's solution said that the issue is related to performing an empty query. So to test, I tried comparing an empty query with {filename:{$exists:1}}. Sure enough, the not-empty query does use an index, but the result is no faster (according to explain). The caveat here is that all 4 cases (query empty vs. not empty and setting enabled vs. not enabled) are all much faster than what shows up in my logs from time to time. The explain is showing around 200ms execution time for all cases. But I sometimes my query takes MUCH longer. In fact, while testing this, I got a 690000ms result! But then it went right back to 200ms.

So long story short, I think the collscan vs. ixscan question was a red herring. I think I have something else going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB covered query is not able to satisfy query from Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351679/mongodb-covered-query-is-not-able-to-satisfy-query-from-index)

Comment: @Veeram that does look like the same issue. I'm trying to add that setting to my mongod.cfg, but what is the syntax? I tried adding: "internalQueryPlannerGenerateCoveredWholeIndexScans:true", but Mongo didn't like that.

Comment: Take  a look 
 [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#setparameter-option).Should be something `setParameter:
   internalQueryPlannerGenerateCoveredWholeIndexScans:true`

Comment: @Veeram. Thanks. I missed the "setParameter" detail. I have that in my config now, and mongo is running, but I'm still seeing collscans: `command: getMore { getMore: 84031837240, collection: "metadata", $db: "testdata" } originatingCommand: { find: "metadata", filter: {}, projection: { filename: true }, $db: "testdata" } planSummary: COLLSCAN`

Comment: Np. Its hard to tell. Restart your server and make sure you are on 3.6.